# Mojolicious, Mojo::Promise, DBI, and parallel requests

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, dbi, mojolicious, mojo

I am new in Mojolicious and playing around with this simple application to return rows from database. It seems to work fine for a single request, however when I use "xargs -n 1 -P 4" to run curl in parallel processes I start seeing "500 Internal Server Error" or "Empty reply from server".

The debug message in the log shows a number of "ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence" and "Worker 101864 has no heartbeat (50 seconds), restarting".

Really appreciate any guidance of what mistake that I made here.

```
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;
use Mojo::Promise;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);

app->config( hypnotoad => { listen => ['http://*:3000'], workers => 4, proxy => 1 });

helper select => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    my ($promise, $column1) = @_;

    my $query = <<~"END";
      SELECT *
      FROM mytable
      WHERE column1 = :column1
    END

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query) or do {
        $promise->reject("Failed to prepare SQL: " . $dbh->errstr);
        return;
    };

    $sth->bind_param(":column1", $column1);
    $sth->execute() or do {
        $promise->reject("Unable to execute SQL: " . $dbh->errstr);
        return;
    };

    # Fetch all rows from the result set
    my $data = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
    $sth->finish();

    return $data;
};

get '/foo/bar' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    my $column1 = $c->param('column1');

    my $promise  = Mojo::Promise->new;
    Mojo::IOLoop->next_tick( sub {
        my $data = $c->select( $promise, $column1 );
        my @records = map { join('|', $_->{column1}, $_->{column2}) } $data->@*;
        my $ret_ref = JSON->new->utf8(1)->pretty(1)->encode( { 'MYRESULT' => \@records });

        $c->render(text => $ret_ref, format => 'json');
        $promise->resolve;
    });

    $promise->wait;
};

app->start;
```

Comment: *"$promise->reject(...)"* I think `$promise` is not defined here, so you should get an error if you enable warnings? It is defined later in the `get` sub but it is too late (and in a different scope so it will not be visible in select helper, right?

Comment: You have a single DBH. Some databases don't permit more than one active STH for a given DBH. Could this be the cause of "fetch out of sequence"? Try moving `my $dbh = ...;` into `select`.

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;` or equivalent. This would have caught the problem HH identified above.

Comment: I don't see the point of using a promise here since you aren't doing anything asynchronous in the anon sub.

Comment: @ikegami: I thought from documentation Mojolicious::Lite enables "strict" and "warnings" by default?

With the promise in anon sub, I need to wait for the DB select to return rows. Perhaps I am entirely on the wrong track and this is not needed?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: you are correct, I've passed in $promise to helper but missed in my copy/paste here. It's amended.

Comment: @esty, Re "*I thought from documentation Mojolicious::Lite enables "strict" and "warnings" by default?*", I mentioned that because the code you had posted wouldn't compile with strictures enabled. (You have since addressed this.)

Comment: Re "*I need to wait for the DB select to return rows.*", No you don't. DBI is not asynchronous. It's functions don't return before the job is done.

Comment: @ikegami: "_DBI is not asynchronous. It's functions don't return before the job is done._" Thanks, I have now removed the use of `Mojo::IOLoop` and `Mojo::Promise`; and also move the DB connection inside `select`.

I'd gladly accept yours as the answer if you replied in the answer section.